# Is it possible to change the layout of a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, border, jtabbedpane

I have an issue with a `JTabbedPane`, I have a border on one of my `JPanel` and I assume the `JTabbedPane` has it's own layout so the border basically expands according to the layout the `JTabbedPane` has, like this:

[image: How it turns out.]

I then tried to change the border of the `JTabbedPane`, using `jTabbedPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());`, though that completely messes it up and it turns out like this:

[image: After changing the layout.]

The way I've been trying to make it look is like this (To clarify, I am trying to achieve the inner border, not the outer one.):

[image: Possible outcome.]

Is it possible to actually change the layout to accommodate what I'm trying to achieve or is there a better way?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, please and thank you. Do let me know if my question needs improving or any other code or clarification is required.

The code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends JFrame
{
    public Test()
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                add(new HomePanel());

                pack();
                setVisible(true);
                setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
    }

    public class HomePanel extends JPanel
    {
        protected JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

        public HomePanel()
        {
            tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
            tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));

            tabbedPane.addTab("Your Bookings", new ShowBookingPanel());

            add(tabbedPane);

        }
    }

    public class ShowBookingPanel extends JPanel
    {
        protected JTable bookingTable;
        protected JScrollPane scrollPane;


        public ShowBookingPanel()
        {
            TitledBorder titledBorder = new TitledBorder("Your Bookings");
            titledBorder.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);
            Border border = new CompoundBorder(titledBorder, new EmptyBorder(40, 50, 40, 50));

            setBorder(border);

            String[] columnNames = {"Check-In Date", "Check-Out Date", "Room Type", "Price", "Action"};
            Object[][] data = {{"22/09/1997", "TBA", "Single", "Priceless"}, {"12/03/2017", "23/04/2017", "Double", "£50"},
                {"12/03/2017", "23/04/2017", "Double", "£50"}, {"12/03/2017", "23/04/2017", "Double", "£50"},
                {"12/03/2017", "23/04/2017", "Double", "£50"}, {"12/03/2017", "23/04/2017", "Double", "£50"},
                {"12/03/2017", "23/04/2017", "Double", "£50"}, {"12/03/2017", "23/04/2017", "Double", "£50"}};

            TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
            {
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            };

            bookingTable = new JTable(model);
            bookingTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
            bookingTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            bookingTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
            bookingTable.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
          bookingTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(bookingTable);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            add(scrollPane);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The way I've been trying to make it look is like this:"* That could be achieved by using a titled border inside an empty border inside another titled border. But what is the purpose of having two titled borders with exactly the same title? It also appears the above has split the imports for `ShowBookingPanel` at the end of the source for `HomePanel`. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (Only one source file, containing one set of imports, one `public` class with `main` method, and one or more default access classes.)

Comment: Sorry I just wanted the one titled border, I didn't remove the original titled border that was on there. The second titled border is the one I was going for. The files are three separate files so I didn't know if it would work if I combined the three together.

Comment: *"The second titled border is the one I was going for."* The 2nd being 'inner' or 'outer'? *"The files are three separate files so I didn't know if it would work if I combined the three together."* It will. But why don't you try it for yourself, rather than telling me what you don't know?

Comment: Thank, I've fixed the code and clarified I am trying to achieve the inner border and not the outer. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
        tabbedPane.addTab("Your Bookings", new ShowBookingPanel());
```

To:

```
        JPanel centeredPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        centeredPanel.add(new ShowBookingPanel());

        tabbedPane.addTab("Your Bookings", centeredPanel);
```

The `GridBagLayout` will center a component as long as the component is added as the only component, without stretching it, using default constraints.